# mongoose populate function does nothing

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using .populate(), however it does not work properly. The "User" has a field called "Tasks" which is an array, this is what i want to store the tasks that are created. At the moment, the task has a "author" field that is the users ID, so i can retrieve tasks that are written by a specific user. however I also want this to show up under in the array of the user.

User Schema:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        validate( value ) {
            if ( !validator.isEmail( value ) ) {
                throw new Error( "Email is unvalid" );
            }
        }
    },
    tasks: [ {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
        ref: "Task"
    } ],
    tokens: [ {
        token: {
            type: String
        }
    } ]
} );

const User = mongoose.model( "User", UserSchema );

module.exports = User;
```

Task Schema:

```
const taskSchema = mongoose.Schema( {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
        ref: "User"
    }
} );

const Task = mongoose.model( "Task", taskSchema );

module.exports = Task;
```

Creation of task:

```
router.post( "/api/tasks", auth, async ( req, res ) => {
    const task = await new Task( { name: req.body.name, description: req.body.description, author: req.user._id } );
    task.save( ( error ) => {
        if ( error ) {
            throw new Error( error );
        }
        if ( !error ) {
            Task.find( {} ).populate( "author" ).exec( ( error, tasks ) => {
                if ( error ) {
                    throw new Error( error );
                }
            } );
        }
    } );
    res.status( 200 ).send();
} );
```

This post route has a auth middleware that just checks if the user is logged in and then returns the user as req.user. It creates a new task with name, description and ID (Which is the users ID, which i can query in the future).

However, in this specific users database, the "tasks" array is empty after running this, but the task was created, and the task has this users ID as "author".

Am i doing this in the wrong order, maybe saving too early?

Thank you for the help

Comment: Change `type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID` to `type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it still does not work though :/

Comment: Also `req.user._id` to `req.body._id`

Comment: No, the req.user._id is coming from my middleware, which is the current user that is signed in, stored as req.user. That works as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code below in my local machine and it's working. I removed `auth` middleware, so now `req.user.author` is `req.body.author` also removed error handling, this is the minimal code that I could provide:

```
app.post("/api/tasks", (req, res) => {
  const task = new Task( { 
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name: req.body.name,
    author: req.body.author,
  });
  task.save(err => {
      User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.author, { $push: {tasks: task._id}}, {new: true}, (err, foundUser) => {
        Task.find({}).populate( "author" ).exec( ( error, foundTasks ) => {
        return res.status(201).send(foundTasks);
        });
      })
      })
  });
```

Comment: Hmm, the tasks array of the user is still empty after creating this task

Comment: Try to console log `req.body.name`, `req.body.description` and `req.user._id` before you save to the database

Comment: That is working correctly. The tasks "author" field is the ID of the user. So i have been able to connect them together ish, but the user does not have that task in the array

Comment: It didn't solve anything? I meant that this was already working. But the user does still not have the task in the "tasks" array

Comment: You might need to remove the database after changing the schema